# How can I add header to compressed string with gzip in python?

Tags: python, c#, gzip, memorystream

I'm trying to compress string by python like a specific C# code but I'm getting a different result. It seems I have to add a header to the compressed result but I don't know how can I add a header to a compressed string in python. This is the C# line which I don't know how would be in python:

```
memoryStream.Read(compressedBytes, CompressedMessageHeaderLength, (int)memoryStream.Length);
```

This is the whole runable C# code

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

namespace Rextester
{
    /// <summary>Handles compressing and decompressing API requests and responses.</summary>
    public class Compression
    {
        #region Member Variables
        /// <summary>The compressed message header length.</summary>
        private const int CompressedMessageHeaderLength = 4;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>Compresses the XML string.</summary>
        /// <param name="documentToCompress">The XML string to compress.</param>
        public static string CompressData(string data)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    zipStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
                }

                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                byte[] compressedBytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length + CompressedMessageHeaderLength];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(
                    BitConverter.GetBytes(plainBytes.Length),
                    0,
                    compressedBytes,
                    0,
                    CompressedMessageHeaderLength
                );

                // Add the header, which is the length of the compressed message.
                memoryStream.Read(compressedBytes, CompressedMessageHeaderLength, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                string compressedXml = Convert.ToBase64String(compressedBytes);

                return compressedXml;
            }
        }
        
 
        #endregion
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            string data = "Hello World!";
            Console.WriteLine(  Compression.CompressData(data) );
            // result would be DAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVEEAKMcKRwMAAAA

        }
    }
}
```

and this is the Python code I wrote:

```py
data = 'Hello World!'

import gzip
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(gzip.compress(data.encode('utf-8'))))

# I expect DAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVEEAKMcKRwMAAAA 
# but I get H4sIACwuuWAC//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQAoxwpHAwAAAA=
```

Comment: One thing is that you are not adding header as done in C# - _"// Add the header, which is the length of the compressed message. memoryStream.Read(compressedBytes, CompressedMessageHeaderLength, (int)memoryStream.Length);"_
"

Comment: I'll change the question

Comment: can you show your python code? Rather than have someone do all the work for you, let's see what you are starting with

Comment: Hi @GarrGodfrey I assume his Python code is: `base64.b64encode(gzip.compress(data.encode('utf-8')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_bytes` to convert length of encoded string:

```py
enc = data.encode('utf-8')
zipped = gzip.compress(enc)
print(base64.b64encode((len(enc)).to_bytes(4, sys.byteorder) + zipped)) # sys.byteorder can be set to concrete fixed value
```

Also it seems that `gzip.compress(enc)` produces slightly different result than C# counterpart (so the overall result will also differ) but this should not be an issue so decompress should handle everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'll start with is that the C# code is not well-suited for cross platform use. The byte order of the length header is dependent on the underlying architecture, as `BitConverter.GetBytes` returns bytes in whatever order the architecture is.

But, for C#, we probably mean windows, which means probably Intel, so Little Endian is very likely.

So, what you need to do is prepend the length of the original data to the compressed data, in Little Endian order. 4 bytes exactly.

```
bdata = data.encode('utf-8')
compressed = gzip.compress(bdata)
header = len(bdata).to_bytes(4,'little')
```

Then, you need to concatenate and convert to base64:

```
print(base64.b64encode(header + compressed))
```

Comment: As Jonathan pointed out in his answer, the results may not be the same. gzip implementations vary. But it should be compatible and readable the the c# decompressor

Comment: This gives, for me, DAAAAB+LCACeRrlgAv/zSM3JyVcIzy/KSVEEAKMcKRwMAAAA
so header is identical but the compression is slightly different.

Comment: for a longer string the result is not equal with the C#, but thanks for your answer

Comment: The compression is going to be different because it is a different implementation.  The header should be identical up to about 2GiB long strings.

Comment: There are 10 levels of compression you can pass to python for gzip. None of them give identical results as C#, however.

Comment: The other answer which I accept gives the same result with C# code.

Comment: They are literally the same code, unless you are running on a bigendian machine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by someone else, the fact that you put that header in in the c# version is a difference.

As well, note that the gzip process can be done in various ways. In C# for example, you can specify a `CompressionLevel` of `Optimal`, `Fastest`, or `NoCompression`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=net-5.0

I'm not familiar enough with Python to say how it will handle gzip compression by default (maybe `Fastest` in C# provides a more or less aggressive algorithm than Python)

Here is your C# code, with the header value set to '0', and outputting with the 3 `CompressionLevels`. Note that it outputs a string value that is 'pretty close' to what you are getting in Python.

You should also ask if it really matters that the values are different. SO long as you can encode and decode, is that enough?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "Hello World!";
        Console.WriteLine(  Compression.CompressData(data, CompressionLevel.Fastest) );
        Console.WriteLine(  Compression.CompressData(data, CompressionLevel.NoCompression) );
        Console.WriteLine(  Compression.CompressData(data, CompressionLevel.Optimal) );
        // result would be DAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVEEAKMcKRwMAAAA
        // but I get       H4sIACwuuWAC//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQAoxwpHAwAAAA=
    }
}

public class Compression
    {
        #region Member Variables
        /// <summary>The compressed message header length.</summary>
        private const int CompressedMessageHeaderLength = 0; // changed to zero
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>Compresses the XML string.</summary>
        /// <param name="documentToCompress">The XML string to compress.</param>
        public static string CompressData(string data, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, compressionLevel, leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    zipStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
                }

                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                byte[] compressedBytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length + CompressedMessageHeaderLength];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(
                    BitConverter.GetBytes(plainBytes.Length),
                    0,
                    compressedBytes,
                    0,
                    CompressedMessageHeaderLength
                );

                // Add the header, which is the length of the compressed message.
                memoryStream.Read(compressedBytes, CompressedMessageHeaderLength, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                string compressedXml = Convert.ToBase64String(compressedBytes);

                return compressedXml;
            }
        }
        
 
        #endregion
    }
```

Output:

> H4sIAAAAAAAEA/NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQAoxwpHAwAAAA=
> H4sIAAAAAAAEAwEMAPP/SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhoxwpHAwAAAA=
> H4sIAAAAAAAAA/NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQAoxwpHAwAAAA=

And at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TI8gwM

Comment: For calling an API I need to compress the data the same as the C# code so first I don't decompress the data second I don't have any choice unless the result be exactly the same as C# code. By the way thanks for your answer